# Remap eject-key in Boot Camp

Tags: windows-7, macbook-pro, boot-camp, remapping

I am running Windows 7 x64 on my MBP within Boot Camp. I would like to remap the eject key to work as a forward-delete and remove the delay from it.

On OS X this is easily achieved with KeyRemap4MacBook and NoEjectDelay

Is it possible to do so when running in Boot Camp?

I've tried a number of tools (AutoHotKey etc.) but none seems to be able to register the key.